# React button component onClick() fires on page load, not onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My onClick isn't firing on click, but rather when the page loads. Here's the relevant code:

App.js

```
callAPI(x) {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/" + x)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }))
      .catch(err => err);
  }

render() {
    <Button
       onClick={this.callAPI('api')}
       type="success"
       className="input-lg">
       Search
    </Button>
```

Button component:

```
import React from "react";

function Button({ type = "default", className, children, onClick }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} className={["btn btn-lg", `btn-${type}`, 
    className].join(" ")}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Andy, could you accept one of the answers to close the question?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```js
<Button onClick={this.callAPI('api')} type="success" className="input-lg">
  Search
</Button>
```

to

```js
<Button onClick={() => this.callAPI('api')} type="success" className="input-lg">
  Search
</Button>
```

You are calling the function as soon as the prop is set instead of when it is clicked. To get the function to fire when clicked you need to pass in a function that has not been called.

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Comment: @AndyWood awesome! If you could accept the answer to close the question that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's becouse you use fire it up automatically. Try something like this.

```js
 <Button
   onClick={() => this.callAPI('api')}
   type="success"
   className="input-lg">
   Search
</Button>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this is the case? I understand that onClick must be a function, but why is `onClick={myOnClick}` when myOnClick is a function ( `myOnClick(){...}`) different to `onClick={()=>myOnClick()}`

Comment: I think it's because onClick={myOnClick} is just reference to function, and you have to bind it to class, because "normal function" have it's own "this scope", so something like onClick={myOnClick.bind(this)} should work, or in constructor line like this.myOnClick = this.myOnClick.bind(this), but when you wrap this with arrow function which do not have own this, then it works. But im not sure so take it into account.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
onClick={this.callAPI('api')}
```

To

```
onClick={() => this.callAPI('api')}
```